# Entity Framework InverseProperty annotation usage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

if I have the following models, am I using the InverseProperty correctly?

```
class Person {
 public int PersonID {get;set;}

 [InverseProperty("Person")]
 public List<Hobbies> Sports {get;set;}

 [InverseProperty("Person")]
 public List<Hobbies> Art {get;set;}

 [InverseProperty("Person")]
 public List<Hobbies> Reading {get;set;}
}

abstract class Hobbies {
 public int HobbiesID {get;set;}
 public string HobbyName {get;set;}
 public int HobbyRating {get;set;}

 public int PersonID {get;set;}
 public Person Person {get;set;}
}

class Sports : Hobbies {}
class Art : Hobbies {}
class Reading : Hobbies {}
```

this works when I don't use the `InverseProperty` but the problem is that the database creates duplicate `PersonID columns` (like 4 of them, looks like 1 for each type that inherits from Hobbies), and I don't want that,

However, when I use `InversePorperty` I get an exception:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship 'x.x.Person_Reading' was not loaded because the type 'x.x.Hobbies' is not available.
```

Comment: You haven't specified the foreign key of the Person property on Hobbies as PersonID. Perhaps that is causing the problem. Add `[ForeignKey("PersonID")]` attribute.

Comment: @odyss-jii will try and let you know, thanks!

Comment: @odyss-jii I got the same exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,
This looks strange : you are creating multiple mapping to the same object qwith different names ?

```
 [InverseProperty("Person")]
 public List<Hobbies> Sports {get;set;}

 [InverseProperty("Person")]
 public List<Hobbies> Art {get;set;}

 [InverseProperty("Person")]
 public List<Hobbies> Reading {get;set;}
```

It should be something like :

```
[InverseProperty("Person")]
public virtual List<Hobbies> Hobbies {get;set;}

[NotMapped]
public List<Sport> Sports 
{
    get
    {
        return this.Hobbies.OfType<Sport>().ToList();
    }
}


[NotMapped]
public List<Art> Art 
{
    get
    {
        return this.Hobbies.OfType<Art>().ToList();
    }
}


[NotMapped]
public List<Reading> Readings 
{
    get
    {
        return this.Hobbies.OfType<Reading>().ToList();
    }
}
```

If you set the property Person in the abstract class, then the mapping must be to the abstract class.

Otherwise, you have to declare the PersonId in the abstract class and then set the Person property in every concrete class using the attribute [ForeignKey("PersonId")]. But this solution is pretty strange.

Secondly, if you want to specify the ForeignKey for the Person, you should use :

```
[ForeignKey("PersonID")]
public virtual Person Person {get;set;}
```

Third : Are you sure you don't need M-N relation? Do you really want every people to create new Hobbies (you would finally have multiple times "Driving" (or whatever) as a hobby).

Comment: yea I want to be able to hold a list of hobbies because for example: list of sport hobbies {soccer:2007, tennis:2008, soccer:2010} so the person can see what sports they played what year, same thing with other ones. But I will try your suggestion, hopefully it will work, I haven't tried what you suggested because I'm new to Entity Framework. THANK YOU!!

Comment: also, what is M-N relation

Comment: That's why I added 3 not mapped properties so you can get each type of hobby with the property(automatically loaded since it is based on the Hobbis property which is marked as "virtual" - means lazy loaded in EF)

Comment: what does not mapped do?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad, M-N relation : Person <-> PersonHobby <-> Hobby. This means you can define a hobby and every people can use the same hobby and don't need to create a new hobby. They will just create the link between a hobby and the person. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)

Comment: @AbdulAhmad, It tells that the property should not be mapped to the database. Since we are retrieving in fact the list of Hobbyes (but selectin only a single type from the list(.OfType<X>())

Comment: will it still create the discriminator column and map the type in there? Thank you for all the help by the way! I really appreciate it

Comment: so in my seed method for putting some test data, how do I assign values to the Sports, Art, and Reading Lists?