# Entity Framework multiple relationships/navigations to entity type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to create this database schema in ASP.NET Core:

[image]

I already tried it with this code without success.

**User**

```
public class User : IdentityUser 
{
    public override string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual UserVisitors Visitors { get; set; }
}
```

UserVisitors

```
public class UserVisitors 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserVisitorId { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public DateTime VisitTime { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserVisitorId")]
    public virtual User UserVisitor { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting this error on the migrations:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property >'User.Visitors' of type 'UserVisitors'. Either manually configure the >relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or >by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Update:

Changed `UserVisitors` to:

```
public class UserVisitors 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public string UserVisitorId { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public DateTime VisitTime { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I can compile it now, but on the database is it wrong. 
Database image: 
[image]

The column `UserVisitorId` doesn't have a relationship to `User.UserID`.

Comment: Shouldn't the type of `User.Visitors` be `ICollection<UserVisitors>`? It looks like you can have more than one entry in `UserVisitors` for one user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework InverseProperty annotation usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179724/entity-framework-inverseproperty-annotation-usage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class User : IdentityUser 
{

    public override string Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserVisitor> UserVisitors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserVisitor> UserVisitors2 { get; set; }
}

public class UserVisitor 
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User {get; set;}
    public virtual User UserVisitor  {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public string UserVisitorId { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public DateTime VisitTime { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
  }
```

Then you need to make proper mappings using `OnModelCreatig` as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserVisitor>()
    .HasOne(x => x.UserVisitor)
    .WithMany(x => x.UserVisitors)

modelBuilder.Entity<UserVisitor>()
    .HasOne(x => x.User)
    .WithMany(x => x.UserVisitors2)
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the same configuration in two places.